# What's the best way to parse secret payload to a js plain object?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I created a secret using the google cloud web UI. I import it directly from a `.env` file. Now I want to use them in a cloud function.

code here:

```js
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const secretManagerServiceClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
const name = 'projects/<my_project_id>/secrets/workflow/versions/latest';

exports.testSecretManager = async (req, res) => {
  const [version] = await secretManagerServiceClient.accessSecretVersion({ name });
  const payload = version.payload.data.toString();
  console.debug(`Payload: ${payload}`);
  const buf = Buffer.from(payload);
  const secrets = dotenv.parse(buf);
  console.debug('secrets:', secrets);
  res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

`version.payload.data.toString()` will give me a raw string of `.env` file like this:

```
APP_PORT=3001
POSTGRES_HOST=db
```

I need to parse it to a js plain object so I can use it through object properties like `payload.data.APP_PORT`. For now, I use [dotenv.parse](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#parse) to parse the raw string to a js plain object. The output like this:

```js
{
  APP_PORT: 3001,
  POSTGRES_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Does google secret manager or `gcloud` cli support create JSON format [secret payload](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/SecretPayload) from a `.env` file? So I can use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON string without using any third-party package?

Comment: Consider storing your secrets in Secret Manager as a JSON string. Why convert data between formats?

Comment: @JohnHanley That should work, but I want to keep using `.env` file.

Comment: Based upon your example, just split each line on the `=` character and strip whitespace. This is easy to do in any language. You do not need a third-party library.

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah, it should work too. My thinking is this tedious work should be done by the secret manager client library. Maybe I should submit a feature request on GitHub issue. Thanks

Comment: Google Secret Manager stores secrets as opaque objects. Reformatting is not part of the service functional design.

Comment: @slideshowp2, you can also write your own lib to do this!

Comment: If you're moving this to Secret Manager, why do you need to keep the `.env` file format? I would either:

1. Update your script to download the secret to a file and `source` that file before spawning your node process (which is how .env files usually work).

2. Drop the coupling to the .env file format and just store your secrets as JSON directly (then you can call JSON.parse).